# Drop down menu is not working?

Tags: php, html, css, web-deployment

I started developing my website and being frank I downloaded the website layout and started to edit the code. Starting I have a normal menu but now I want to change it into a dropdown menu and wrote my code in index.xhtml code as

```
<ul id="nav">
  <ul id="nav-pages">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <a href="octet2.xhtml">Oracle</a>
    <ul>
<li><a href="octet2.xhtml">Sql</a></li>
        <li><a href="octet2.xhtml">Pl Sql</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my .css  code

```
#nav { float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; margin: 40px 0 0   0; border-top: 5px #eee solid;border-bottom: 5px #eee solid; padding: 12px 0 8px 0; z-index: 999; display: block;  }

#nav ul { clear: left; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;display: block;  }
#nav ul li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; right: 50%;  }
#nav ul li a {  margin: 0 0 0 1px; padding: 3px 0; font-size: 16px; color: #444; text-transform: uppercase;}
#nav ul li a:hover { color: #0072bc; display: block;  }
#nav li span { padding: 0 20px; color: #444; font-size: 16px; } 
#nav li a.current{ color: #0072bc;  }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dropdown menu sounds like a javascript feature. You should also download the scripts involved with this template.

Comment: Why is your `<span></span>` empty?

Comment: It's used as a clear padding, `span { padding: 0 20px; }`

Comment: @Fred I do not have any specific use of it so left it empty.

Comment: @DaveChen I am just using a basic Drop down which was based on Html and CSS ... the span code you have advised haven't made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing your three `<ul>` or posting the whole code.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <ul id="nav-pages">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="octet2.xhtml">Oracle</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="octet2.xhtml">Sql</a></li>
                <li><a href="octet2.xhtml">Pl Sql</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

EDIT: your css is wrong

```
#nav { float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; margin: 40px 0 0   0; border-top: 5px #eee solid;border-bottom: 5px #eee solid; padding: 12px 0 8px 0; z-index: 999; display: block;  }

#nav ul {  clear: left; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;display: block;  }
#nav li:hover ul { left: 0;}//that one display the subcategories
#nav ul li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; right: 50%; width: 150px;  }
#nav li ul {left: -9999px;}// that one hide them when not in hover state
#nav ul li a {  margin: 0 0 0 1px; padding: 3px 0; font-size: 16px; color: #444; text-transform: uppercase;}
#nav ul li a:hover { color: #0072bc; display: block;  }
#nav li span { padding: 0 20px; color: #444; font-size: 16px; }
```

Comment: Thanks u edited .... can u tell me where the error is now

Comment: It's in comments line after the added CSS :-)

Comment: now I am getting it VERTICAL ... :(

Comment: the positionning of your menu is a matter of CSS, now that it works, you can do the layout.

Comment: but why it is coming in vertical style this is my css code for menu

Comment: Because your CSS is written to make it look this way, the menu you downloaded was meant to be a horizontal menu with vertical dropdown. If you want a vertical menu with horizontal dropdown, try displaying in blocks instead of floating the parts or look at a tutorial like the one at http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31536/discussion-between-template-and-jay-zus)